# How to compare Go slices with NaN elements in unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, go

I need to compare 2 slices in unit tests and I thought `assert` package should solve this but it doesn't work with NaNs:

```
import (
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func CallMe() []float64 {
    return []float64{math.NaN()}
}

func TestCallMe(t *testing.T) {
    assert.Equal(t, []float64{math.NaN()}, CallMe())
}
```

The output is:

```
            Error:          Not equal: 
                            expected: []float64{NaN}
                            actual  : []float64{NaN}
                            
                            Diff:
            Test:           TestCallMe
```

I understand that it's a property of NaN to be not equal to itself but on the other hand I receive the expected result from the function.

I wonder how to solve that - to have a concise unit test assertion and a clear output?

As an alternative I can avoid using `assert` and call `math.IsNaN` on every element of both slices but that will look extra verbose in unit tests.

Comment: [`math.IsNan()`](https://pkg.go.dev/math#IsNaN)

Comment: Write the loop yourself. Not everything can be done or is worth an assertion library.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done actually, but I wonder if someone knows a more clever solution.

Comment: No one wants to maintain clever, they want simple and obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp) package is typically recommended for more complex comparisons. [cmpopts.EquateNaNs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp@v0.5.9/cmp/cmpopts#EquateNaNs) can be used to easily compare data structures which may contain NaNs.

```golang
package calc_test

import (
    "math"
    "testing"

    "github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp"
    "github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp/cmpopts"
)

func calc(n float64) []float64 {
    return []float64{n, math.NaN()}
}

func TestCalc(t *testing.T) {
    want := []float64{1, math.NaN()}

    got := calc(1)  // PASS.
    if !cmp.Equal(got, want, cmpopts.EquateNaNs()) {
        t.Errorf("calc: got = %v; want = %v", got, want)
    }

    got = calc(2)   // FAIL with differences.
    if diff := cmp.Diff(want, got, cmpopts.EquateNaNs()); diff != "" {
        t.Errorf("calc: diff (-want +got) = \n%s", diff)
    }
}
```